# Slowly expanding row of Gridlayout

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a scrollview and inside of it, is a gridlayout view. Inside that gridlayout, I have a list with checkbox for each item. Whenever user select an item, the bottom row should expand slowly and show details of the selected item. This is my attempt with boxview but it doesn't work. Any suggestion how to fix this?

```
void OnChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (statusBar == null)
        {
            statusBar = new BoxView { Color = Color.FromHex("#33B5E5"), HeightRequest = 0 };
            mainGrid.Children.Add(statusBar, 0, 4);
            Grid.SetColumnSpan(statusBar, 2);

            var animate = new Animation(d => statusBar.HeightRequest = d, 1, statusBar.Height, Easing.SpringIn);

            animate.Commit(this, "a");
        }

        if (((CheckBox)sender).Checked)
            checkedCount++;
        else
            checkedCount--;

        if(checkedCount == 0)
        {
            mainGrid.Children.Remove(statusBar);
            statusBar = null;
            return;
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE :**

This still doesn't work. **The boxview shows up instantly**.

So I changed my code as per suggestion :

```
statusBar = new BoxView { Color = Color.FromHex("#33B5E5"), HeightRequest = 0 };
            mainGrid.Children.Add(statusBar, 0, 4);
            Grid.SetColumnSpan(statusBar, 2);

            var animate = new Animation(d => statusBar.HeightRequest = d, 1, 1000, Easing.SpringIn);
            animate.Commit(this, "a", length: 10000);//animation takes 2 sec to complete
```

Answer (score 1):

Add some time to your animation.

```
animate.Commit(this, "a",length:2000);//animation takes 2 sec to complete
```

I don't understand your code.

```
 var animate = new Animation(d => statusBar.HeightRequest = d, 1, statusBar.Height, Easing.SpringIn);
```

You are setting the height above to **0** `HeightRequest = 0` and starting your animation at **1** and ending at 0 this will probably `close` your boxview. Try adding a larger value in the end attribute to get your desired animation e.g.

```
var animate = new Animation(d => statusBar.HeightRequest = d, 1, 100, Easing.SpringIn);
```

Comment: So I updated my code, but the boxview shows instantly instead of animation.

Comment: Increase the time `length:4000` or any desired value.

Comment: It's set to 10,000.

Comment: Can you change your start value to 0 and then try again. `var animate = new Animation(d => statusBar.HeightRequest = d, 0, 1000, Easing.SpringIn);`

Comment: It just pops up. No animation

Comment: Have you set your grid row height to auto?

Comment: Yes that's it I tested using `*` and `auto`. Setting it to star won't show your animation this might be because it might need to calculate space for other rows. You need to set it to auto.

Comment: So I put the scrollview inside of stacklayout and add the boxview to stacklayout. Now it's working!

Comment: For debugging, long animations are fine. For production, aim for 200-300ms (per [Google](https://material.io/design/motion/speed.html#duration) and [MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/vis-animations)).